# Traduction du mot indeed dans un contexte mathématique

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, mathématiques

> We have to show that A=B. Indeed, adding and subtracting C to the right hand of Eq. (1) and substituting Eq. (2) yields...
>
> Nous devons démontrer que A = B. En effet, additionnant et soustrayant C à la droite de l'Éq. (1) et remplaçant l'Éq. (2) fourni...
>
> Nous devons démontrer que A = B. Effectivement, additionnant et soustrayant C à la droite de l'Éq. (1) et remplaçant l'Éq. (2) fourni...

*En effet*, *effectivement*, ou bien quelque chose d'autre interprète mieux *indeed* dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans ce contexte, je dirais plutôt "pour cela" ou "à cet effet". Il s'agit d'exprimer que ce qui suit a pour effet (pour conséquence) ce que l'on veut démontrer.

Comment: Comme je l'ai indiqué en commentaire d'une autre réponse, "en effet" est possible. Je l'ai souvent lu, au contraire de "effectivement" que je n'aime pas trop. Peut-être que j'ai trop lu "en effet" pour être capable de l'apprécier à sa juste valeur.

Answer (score 0):

« En effet » est souvent utilisé dans le texte mathématique français et il y signifie souvent [« parce que »](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/en%20effet/fr-fr/) ; Le sens « parce que » est confirmé par le [reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/CollabDict.aspx?lang=fr&srcLang=1036&targLang=1036&searchIn=all&allPairs=1&sort=1&word=en+effet). 
Il est aussi confirmé par le [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?12;s=2724016335;r=1;nat=;sol=1;) :

> [Avec valeur de conj. de coordin.] Sert de liaison; ne se place pas nécessairement au début de la proposition qu'il introduit. **Synon. car.**.

D'après mes lectures, des mathématiciens reconnaissent cette valeur à l'emploi de « en effet » en mathématiques.

Une utilisation typique est comme suit ;

- Lorsque [1], la limite éventuelle ne peut être que [2]. **En effet**, à cause de [3], on a nécessairement [4], et ceci pour tout [5].

C'est dans ce contexte que la locution est reconnue comme exprimant la cause.

Considérons les phrases suivantes ;

> Nous devons démontrer que A = B. En effet, additionnant et soustrayant C à la droite de l'Éq. (1) et remplaçant l'Éq. (2) fourni…

Elles se paraphrasent comme suit ;

> Nous devons démontrer que A = B. **C'est vrai car**, additionnant et soustrayant C à la droite de l'Éq. (1) et remplaçant l'Éq. (2) fourni…

La locution est employée de façon elliptique ; on nous dit bien qu'elle a *valeur de locution conjonctive de coordination* : ce n'est pas exactement une locution conjonctive. Il n'y a pas de notion de causalité dans l'anglais « indeed ». C'est pour cette raison qu'il me semble ici préférable de traduire « indeed » par « **assurément** ».

Comment: En tant que scientifique (du moins j'essaie), je n'aime pas trop le terme "assurément", pas assez précis à mon goût. On n'assure pas que quelque chose est vraie, on cherche à le prouver En revanche, "en effet" a souvent été utilisé. (Ce n'est pas moi qui ait downvoté. Mais quel est le terme français pour ça ?)

Comment: @Damien Je suppose que vous voulez dire « quel est un synonyme pour « en effet » ou une paraphrase ? », et pas le «  terme français pour « Indeed » ». Pour paraphraser je n'ai que l'explication donnée par un mathématicien qui écrit simplement que cela signifie « parce que », ce qui correspond à un sens des dictionnaires. (J'ai longtemps été dans l'embarras de pouvoir donner un sens qui soit syntaxiquement logique à cette locution dans le contexte des preuves.)  (champ 1)

Comment: @Damien Cependant, en anglais on ne traduit pas « Indeed » par « parce que » ou « car », d'où, dans une traduction de l'anglais, puisque il n'insiste pas sur la causalité, on reste dans l'esprit de l'original. On peut traduire par « en effet » mais selon le sens premier de cette locution (assurément, en fait, effectivement). Je suis d'accord sur le point que «en fait » ou « effectivement » seraient des traductions plus expressives dans ce contexte, mais je n'en voit pas beaucoup d'autres pour rester près du sens de « Indeed ». (champ 2)

Comment: @Damien  J'étais soucieux de ne pas introduire la causalité où l'anglais ne le fait pas. (fin)

Comment: Connaissant le français beaucoup mieux que l'anglais, et ayant écrit un certain nombre d'articles scientifiques (surtout en anglais, malheureusement pour les lecteurs), j'ai surtout cherché ce que mettrait un mathématicien français dans ces circonstances, sans chercher à être très proche du mot anglais. Le mot "assurément" me choque, sans qu'il me soit facile de dire pourquoi.

Comment: Le mot "indeed" introduit une preuve. Il y a donc causalité, même si cette causalité est davantage dans la tournure générale que dans ce mot lui-même.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88877/discussion-between-lph-and-damien).